# How to render a custom block with variables from another custom block twig template

Tags: views, blocks, hooks

I have a custom block with some values I can access in the template of that block, for example the `product_type` variable. In the same template file I'm adding another view block with `{{ drupal_block('views_block:my-view-block_1', {product_type: 'clothes'}) }}`.

For that block I implemented this hook.

```php
function myModule_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
// I want to access that product_type variable in this hook
// because I want to add a filter.
$view->display_handler->display['display_options']['filters']['field_product_type_target_id']['default_value'] = $product_type;
}
```

The hook is invoked, but I cannot get the value of `product_type`. I'm not sure that is the correct way to achieve it, but I really need to pass that value from first block to second block to filter out results. It's been 2 days I'm trying to figure this out. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are passed from PHP/preprocess to Twig, but ***never*** vice versa.

Instead of preprocessesing the filter of the second block, replace the product type filter in the 2nd views block with a "contextual filter" , and pass `product_type` as contextual argument to the view. And finally - since you are already using Twig Tweak module - use `drupal_view` to render the 2nd views block:

`{{ drupal_view('MY_VIEW_ID', 'MY_VIEWDISPLAY_ID', product_type) }}`

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked like a charm.